# Exception using Scanner multiple times in Java 1.8

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm not understanding why I get an exception when using Scanner in the main method and again in a called method in the same class.  Here's the code:

```
import java.utils.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    private void multiplyNumber(int number) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a second number: ");
        String tmp = input.next();
        input.close();
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
        int product = number * num2;
        System.out.println("Product is: " + product);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ScannerTest pt = new ScannerTest();
        String tmp = "";

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        tmp = input.next();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(tmp);
        input.close();
        pt.multiplyNumber(number);
    }
}
```

When I input a number (say 5) to the request from main it then calls the multiplyNumber method which gives me the second number prompt but then throws an exception:

[image: []Scanner exception[1]]

Any thoughts on why I get the "Unknown Source" exception?  Thanks.

Comment: The exception part didn't get posted.  Here's the exception I see:

Comment: Enter a number: 5
Enter a second number: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at ScannerTest.multiplyNumber(ScannerTest.java:7)
 at ScannerTest.main(ScannerTest.java:28)